# joomla how to get getListFooter on home page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6, joomla1.7

I am using joomla 1.7.3

I have a large number of articles on home page with pagination. I have to show a drop down box for users to choose number of items to show on home page.

I have edited

> \components\com_content\views\featured\tmpl\default.php

and changed

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
```

then home page starts to show the drop down but its not working. then I have wrapped the pagination section with a form ( I dont know the action value) then when I change the drop down value, the page gets refreshed but number of items displaying is not changing

Pleaes help

Answer (score -1):

Easy. Here's the form you want:

```
<form action="." method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
    <select id="limit" name="limit" class="inputbox" size="1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15" selected="selected">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="0">All</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

You shouldn't even need `getListFooter()`; just include the above code.

Comment: And how do you expect to set the selected value with the above code.. It's a poor way of handling it. It should be wrapped with a  <form action="<?php echo $link;?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
 @john K